# Bootcamp to Terminal Server

Tags: mac, terminal-services

We have a user using a Mac with Bootcamp and Windows installed.

Connecting to a Windows 2008 R2 Terminal Server from the Windows install the Mac keyboard does not map correctly.

Does anyone know if you can install an Apply keyboard layout on the Widows server to fix this?

Or if there is any other fix for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you focus on the terminal client machine to accommodate your needs, rather than making changes on the server.

One option is to just get a typical PC keyboard and plug that in, everything should function normally. It is just another x86 box running Windows, afterall.

If you want to use the Apple keyboard still, then use a utility such as [MapKeyboard](http://www.inchwest.com/mapkeyboard.htm), [KeyTweak](http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/), or [Sharpkeys](http://www.randyrants.com/sharpkeys/) to remap specific keys to function as you require.